# OneDrive on Yosemite doesn't synchronize new files

Tags: onedrive

I'm using the OneDrive on Yosemite and I`m able to synchronize the files that are already in the cloud, but the new ones that I copied into the OneDrive local folder do not synchronize to the cloud. The OneDrive status stay "Scaning files" for days.

Comment: I've started a vote to move this over to Superuser - Stackoverflow is for _programming_ problems

Comment: Sorry about that, I accessed the http://msdn.microsoft.com/onedrive/ and I was redirect to stack overflow and I did not realize that.